# Creating a Method that prints out an Array

Tags: arrays, string

I'm working on an assignment where the user enters a number of elements that are then stored and sorted in an array of Strings.  I have to create a method that prints out the sorted the array without using the Array class.  My issue is that I have to insert a comma in between the elements entered.  So right now my output looks something like this.

alpha, bravo, delta,

How do I get rid of the last comma?  Below is my method.

```
public static void arrayPrint(String[] argsArray)
{

       for (int i=0; i<argsArray.length; i++)
       {

           if (i <= argsArray.length)
           System.out.print(argsArray[i]);
           System.out.print(", ");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will solve it :

```
public static void arrayPrint(String[] argsArray)
  {

       for (int i=0; i<argsArray.length; i++)
       {

           if (i <= argsArray.length)
           System.out.print(argsArray[i]);

           if (i != argsArray.length-1)
           System.out.print(", ");
       }
 }
```

in addition, you could pass on that `if (i <= argsArray.length)` piece of code, because the `for` loop has already validated this query.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I don't why I have a hard time wrapping my head around argArray.length -1.

Answer (score 0):

Change `System.out.print(", ");` to this:

```
if (i != argsArray.length -1)
    System.out.print(", ");
```

Full method:

```
public static void arrayPrint(String[] argsArray)
{

       for (int i=0; i<argsArray.length; i++)
       {

           if (i <= argsArray.length)
           System.out.print(argsArray[i]);
           if (i != argsArray.length -1)
              System.out.print(", ");
       }
}
```